# Opening ENVI file in R gives error

Tags: raster, r, envi

I'm new at using GIS with R and I'm trying to open an ENVI file containing hyperspectral data following the suggestions from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474186/r-how-to-read-envi-hdr-file, but I don't seem to be able to do so. I tried three different approaches but all of them failed. I also can't seem to find any other posts where my problem is described.

```
# install.packages("rgdal")
# install.packages("raster")
# install.packages("caTools")
library("rgdal")
library("raster")
library("caTools")

dirname <- "S:/LAB-cavender/4_Project_Folders/oakWilt/oak_wilt_image_analyses/R_input/6.15.2021 - Revisions/ENVI export/AISA/Resampled_flights"
filename <- file.path(dirname, "AISA_Flight_4_resampled")
file.exists(filename)
```

1. The first option that I tried was using file name only

```
    x <- read.ENVI(filename)
```

But I got the following error message:

```
#Error in read.ENVI(filename) :
#  read.ENVI: Could not open input file: S:/LAB-cavender/4_Project_Folders/oakWilt/oak_wilt_image_analyses/R_input/6.15.2021 - Revisions/ENVI export/AISA/Resampled_flights/AISA_Flight_4_resampled
#In addition: Warning message:
#  In nRow * nCol * nBand : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

2. I tried then the second option which is using file name + header file name read using *file.path*

```
    headerfile <- file.path(dirname, "AISA_Flight_4_resampled")
    x <- read.ENVI(filename = filename,headerfile = headerfile)
```

Again, I got an error message that says:

```
#Error in read.ENVI(filename = filename, headerfile = headerfile) :
#  read.ENVI: Could not open input header file: S:/LAB-cavender/4_Project_Folders/oakWilt/oak_wilt_image_analyses/R_input/6.15.2021 - Revisions/ENVI export/AISA/Resampled_flights/AISA_Flight_4_resampled
```

3. Finally, I tried the third option by using file name + header file name read using *readLines*

```
hdr_file <- readLines(con = "S:/LAB-cavender/4_Project_Folders/oakWilt/oak_wilt_image_analyses/R_input/6.15.2021 - Revisions/ENVI export/AISA/Resampled_flights/AISA_Flight_4_resampled.hdr")
x <- read.ENVI(filename = filename,headerfile = hdr_file)
```

But I got the error message:

```
#Error in read.ENVI(filename = filename, headerfile = hdr_file) :
#  read.ENVI: Could not open input header file: ENVIdescription = {  Spectrally Resampled File. Input number of bands: 63, output number of bands: 115. [Fri Jun 25 16:57:21 2021]}samples = 5187lines   = 6111bands   = 115header offset = 0file type = ENVI Standarddata type = 4interleave = bilsensor type = Unknownbyte order = 0map info = {UTM, 1.000, 1.000, 482828.358, 5029367.353, 7.5000000000e-001, 7.5000000000e-001, 15, North, WGS-84, units=Meters}coordinate system string = {PROJCS["UTM_Zone_15N",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-93.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]}default bands = {46,31,16}wavelength units = Nanometersdata ignore value = -9999.00000000e+000band names = { Resampled
#    In addition: Warning message:
#      In if (!file.exists(headerfile)) stop("read.ENVI: Could not open input header file: ",  :
#                                              the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 1):

To read an ENVI file with `read.ENVI`, you give the data file as the first parameter, and optionally the header file as the second parameter.

For example, I have two files, `ice` (with *NO* extension) and `ice.hdr`.

[image]

I can then do either of these two:

```
> re = read.ENVI("/tmp/test/data/ice")
> re = read.ENVI("/tmp/test/data/ice", headerfile="/tmp/test/data/ice.hdr")
```

Make sure for you both these parts exist. Try using `file.info`:

```
> file.info("/tmp/test/data/ice")
                     size isdir mode               mtime               ctime
/tmp/test/data/ice 136192 FALSE  644 2021-06-29 12:02:31 2021-06-29 12:06:07
                                 atime   uid  gid    uname   grname
/tmp/test/data/ice 2021-06-29 12:06:38 12818 1001 rowlings rowlings
> file.info("/tmp/test/data/ice.hdr")
                       size isdir mode               mtime               ctime
/tmp/test/data/ice.hdr  230 FALSE  644 2021-06-29 12:02:36 2021-06-29 12:02:36
                                     atime   uid  gid    uname   grname
/tmp/test/data/ice.hdr 2021-06-29 12:02:50 12818 1001 rowlings rowlings
```

Alternatively, try the `raster` function from the `raster` package, and feed it the path to the data file (not the header file) but the header file must be the name of the data file with `.hdr` on:

```
> rr = raster("/tmp/test/data/ice")
>
```

If none of this helps then I think we need your data files - if you can put them on a sharing site (Dropbox, OneDrive, etc etc) and make them available then we have more chance of helping.

Comment: thank you so much! This worked out.